# Alfresco task listener variables

Tags: workflow, listener, alfresco

I have two task listeners,the first on `event="create"` the second on `event="complete"`.
In the first i'm counting files when task was created, in the second when task completed and looking if the number of files is equal throw an error. But this not work, i have  `ReferenceError: "count" is not defined`.

```
<extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
               var count = 0;
               for (var i = 0; i < bpm_package.children.length; i++) 
                {
                  count++;
                }
        ]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>

        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
               var count_new = 0;
               for (var i = 0; i < bpm_package.children.length; i++) 
                {
                  count_new++;
                }
                if (count ==count_new)
                 {
                    var message = "\n\nAdd files\n";
                    throw new Error(message + "\n");
                 }
    ]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem of how to define a variable. You need to add `execution.setVariable ('zvernennya_count', count);` to the first task listener.

But it does not solve my problem of testing attachments, because the variable `count` is defined once, and the task has multi-user access, and when the first users task is completed, the next users task already has  variable `count_new` different from `count`.

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003822/alfresco-%D1%81heck-for-adding-files/31024711#31024711 , you need to re initialize the count variable

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you need to add it in your model. you are just setting variable but that variable has to be defined in the workflowmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting  **ReferenceError** because that "count" variable is not visible to other Listener.

If you need to persist the value of variable you have to define variable in the workflow model use that variable in place of local variable count.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/wf-task-model.html

This should give you good starting point.